# Routing error "uninitialized constant Info"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a module in /lib

```
Module Info
class Inf

  def getNum
    num = Array.new

    num.push(2,1)

  end

end
```

In the controller informations_controller I have 'require Info' and the follow code:

```
  def index
    @informations = Info::Inf.getNum().num

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @informations }
    end
  end
```

But it always gives the error

```
Routing Error

uninitialized constant Info
```

Since the router I have defined "root :to =>  'informations#index'" what could be missing?

Comment: Does your module file really have `Module Info` (with a capital M)?

Comment: And also does it really have no 'end'

Comment: Yes you're both correct! thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it should be `module` not Module and also you should name file `info.rb` and also you should be sure lib is in auto_load paths in`config/application.rb`

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

so it should be something like this `lib/info.rb`:

```
module Info
  class Inf
    ...
  end
end
```